# Plot magnetic field of a satelite's orbit in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, satellite

I made a GUI in MATLAB and at one point 1 got a 3d plot of the earth where i show the orbit of a satelite.What i want is to show in every point(for instance, i increase the coordinates[latitude,longitude] by 1 degree and keep the same altitude) of that orbit the magnitude of the magnetic field of the earth with vectors(northward vector,eastward vector,downward vector).This is a part of the code but it doesn't work

```
magnetic_field_ = igrf(time,T(i,1),T(i,2),T(i,3),'geodetic');
[hh(i,1) hh(i,2) hh(i,3)]=igrf(time,T(i,1),T(i,2),T(i,3),'geodetic');
```

.
.
.

```
% earth
axesm('globe','geoid',wgs84Ellipsoid)
load topo
meshm(topo, topolegend, size(topo)); 
demcmap(topo);
hold on;
```

.
.

```
 vv=lla2ecef([T(i,1),T(i,2),T(i,3)]);
 spheroid = referenceEllipsoid('GRS 80');

[Bh(1) Bh(2) Bh(3)]=ned2ecefv(hh(i,1),hh(i,2),hh(i,3),T(i,1),T(i,2),T(i,3));%,spheroid,'degrees');
h=quiver3(vv(1),vv(2),vv(3),Bh(1),Bh(2),Bh(3),0.1,'r');
h.MaxHeadSize=3;
hold on
```

Comment: T(i,1) T(i,2) T(i,3) is Latitude Longtitude Altitude

Comment: You need to show a [mcve] if you need help